# CNN in Pytorch: labels for a custom dataset

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have a very basic question that would be really helpful for getting me started on a deep learning project I'm running. I'm planning to apply a 3D convolutional network using pytorch to a large number of medical images to predict a single numerical value. My question is, for the labelled instances (ranging from 0-40) that I'll be using to train my CNN model - how exactly are the labels of the training set fed to the model? Is it usually contained within a csv file that you load in or otherwise is the label embedded in the name of the image or alternatively a folder that contain images of the same class (e.g. folder for "0", folder for "1")?

Any help you could provide would be really appreciated!

Comment: you could use a csv file to do that but most of the times deep learning libraries use folder names as their labels or class names in alphabetical order. So, if you have 40 classes of those images. then the output will give the class value from 0 to 39. You have to print the class according to the output value. This happens for sure, atleast in keras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Functions are very useful if your classes are arranged in folder structure
Provided your folder structure to be like this

> train
>
> > class1
> > class2
> > ...
> > class_n

> test
>
> > class1
> > class2
> > ...
> > class_n

```
train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + '/train', transform=train_transforms)
test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + '/test', transform=test_transforms)  
print(train_data.classes) # will print all your classes
```

Second option what you have is:
torch.utils.data.Dataset is an abstract class representing a dataset. Your custom dataset should inherit Dataset and override the following methods:

`__len__()` so that len(dataset) returns the size of the dataset.
`__getitem__()` to support the indexing such that **dataset[i]** can be used to get ith sample
Eg of writing custom Dataset

```
class CustomDatasetFromCsvLocation(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, csv_path):
        """
        Custom dataset example for reading image locations and labels from csv
        but reading images from files
        Args:
            csv_path (string): path to csv file
        """
        # Transforms
        self.to_tensor = transforms.ToTensor()
        # Read the csv file
        self.data_info = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=None)
        # First column contains the image paths
        self.image_arr = np.asarray(self.data_info.iloc[:, 0])
        # Second column is the labels
        self.label_arr = np.asarray(self.data_info.iloc[:, 1])
        # Third column is for an operation indicator
        self.operation_arr = np.asarray(self.data_info.iloc[:, 2])
        # Calculate len
        self.data_len = len(self.data_info.index)

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # Get image name from the pandas df
        single_image_name = self.image_arr[index]
        # Open image
        img_as_img = Image.open(single_image_name)

        # Check if there is an operation
        some_operation = self.operation_arr[index]
        # If there is an operation
        if some_operation:
            # Do some operation on image
            # ...
            # ...
            pass
        # Transform image to tensor
        img_as_tensor = self.to_tensor(img_as_img)

        # Get label(class) of the image based on the cropped pandas column
        single_image_label = self.label_arr[index]

        return (img_as_tensor, single_image_label)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.data_len
```

Answer (score -1):

Roughly, you need to define a **criterion** which is the Loss function, for example.

```
 import torch.nn as nn
 criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

Then you need to divide each data entry into two, the image and the corresponding label. Feed the images to your CNN, evaluate with criterion (forward pass) and finally update the CNN (back-propagation).

```
# Forward pass
outputs = CNN(images)
loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

# Back pass
loss.backward()
```

I suggest you to read some code examples of CNN from GitHub, perhaps a Python Notebook is the best option.